What does the 还 do in 啊，还是有点问题的?
啊，还是有点问题的。
What does the 还 do in this sentence?
Context: the thinker of the sentence realized that there was a problem in a past event.

it means "still" in this context

Judging from this Reddit post, it looks like you're reading the web novel 《一不小心和醋精结婚了》 by 一枚纽扣.  Here are the relevant examples from the web novel:

那天结束了之后，楚义特地去了医院，各项检查完，他都没什么问题啊。
啊，还是有点问题的。
他出血了。
并且喜提了个很尴尬的经历，那个医生一脸严肃地告诉他，近期不能再有性生活，叫他节制点。

This is the common usage meaning "still" or "as before" (emphasizing something remains unchanged).  The tests in the hospital were completed and there were no problems.  Yet, he still has two problems: he's bleeding, and the doctor says he cannot have a sex life in the short term.


他不知道这位秦先生来找他干什么。
照第二天的情况来看，这分明就是江湖不再见的节奏嘛。
所以，是……
掉钱了？
掉身份证了？
还想再来一次？

He has said goodbye to 秦先生, but 秦先生 has come to find him.  He's mulling over the possibilities in his head.  Here the 还 is "still" (highlighting an unchanged situation) again: he's thinking that maybe 秦先生 wants to continue seeing him.


虽然他去酒吧确实是有想寻点艳遇的心思，但谁会想到啊这个愿望竟然还就真的实现了。

This usage emphasizes something unexpected happened; my dictionary has this definition:

表示对某建事物，没想到如此，而居然如此。

So in the story, 还 is added to contrast what a person would expect (he won't be able to hook up) with what happened (he actually hooked up).
I'd translate it to something like this:

Although he went to the bar with the idea of hooking up, but who would of thought 'ey?  That this wish would be fulfilled.


还[hái] = 依然，仍然 - still; yet; remain; nonetheless

还: still
还是：还
啊，还是有点问题的。
Ah, there is still a bit of a problem
You could just write:
还有点问题。
(We) still have a small problem.
